# Fetching AJAX results from three endpoints, with error handling

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have a requirement in which I need to get data by making AJAX calls. First search for data in `endPoint1`, if not found then in `endPoint2`, if not found then in `endPoint3`. But if any of the `endPoint` returns data, then there is no need to make further REST calls.

I have achieved the functionality, but the code looks spaghetti.

If possible, please suggest a better approach to reduce this call indentation.

```
function myAjaxFunction(endPoint) {
    // returns promise 
}

function checkForData() {
    myAjaxFunction(endPoint1)
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) { return "Data found"; }
            else {
                myAjaxFunction(endPoint2)
                    .then(function (data) {
                        if (data.d.results.length > 0) { return "Data found"; }
                        else {
                            myAjaxFunction(endPoint3)
                                .then(function (data) {
                                    if (data.d.results.length > 0) { return "Data found"; }
                                    else {
                                        console.info("sorry data not exist");
                                    }
                                }, function (e) {
                                    console.error()
                                });
                        }
                    }, function (e) {
                        console.error()
                    });
            }
        },
        function (data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) { return "Data found"; }
            else {
                return "not found.";
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest passing in an array of endpoints so you can have one loop that calls an endpoint and looks at the result without repeating any code:

```
function checkForData(endPoints) {
    let i = 0;

    function next() {
        if (i < endPoints.length) {
            return myAjaxFunction(endPoints[i++]).then(function(data) {
                if (data && data.d && data.d.results && data.d.results.length > 0) {
                    return data.d.results;
                } else {
                    return next();
                }
            });
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return Promise.resolve().then(next);
}

checkForData([endPoint1, endPoint2, endPoint3]).then(function(result) {
    // result here
    if (result) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log("no data found");
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Note: I also put `.then()` on the same line as its parent function to avoid an extra level of indent.

Comment: @nbi - Any feedback on any of the answers here?

Comment: @Jfriedn00 thanks for answering... Yes it make code lot easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting an environment that supports `async`/`await` (translation: non-Internet Explorer) or are using a transpiler, then this is as simple as a try-catch containing a `for..of` loop:

```js
async function checkForData() {
  try {
    for (let endpoint of [1, 2, 3]) {
      let data = await myAjaxFunction(endpoint);

      if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
        return 'Data found';
      }
    }

    console.log('sorry data not exist');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('error occurred:', e.message);
  }
}

checkForData().then(result => console.log(result));



// mock for myAjaxFunction - wait 1 second and return data for endpoint 2
function myAjaxFunction(endPoint) {
  console.log('calling endpoint', endPoint);

  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    .then(() => ({
      d: {
        results: endPoint === 2 ? ['a', 'b'] : []
      }
    }));
}
```

If you don't have the liberty to use `async`/`await`, another elegant approach is to make use of Observables. The following uses observables and has the same outcome as what you are attempting to do:

```js
function checkForData() {
  var endpoints = [1, 2, 3];

  return Rx.Observable.from(endpoints)
    .concatMap(myAjaxFunction)
    .find(function (data) {
      return data.d.results.length;
    })
    .map(function (found) {
      if (found) {
        return 'Data found';
      }
      console.log('sorry data not exist');
    })
    .toPromise()
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('error occurred:', e);
    });
}

checkForData().then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});



// mock for myAjaxFunction - wait 1 second and return data for endpoint 2
function myAjaxFunction(endPoint) {
  console.log('calling endpoint', endPoint);

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    })
    .then(function() {
      return {
        d: {
          results: endPoint === 2 ? ['a', 'b'] : []
        }
      };
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about promises is that you can chain them, by returning a new promise within the callback. You can also return a value, which is implicity wrapped in `Promise.resolve`.

This way, the code will pass either data, or the result of the next `myAjaxFunction` along the chain

```
function checkForData() {
    myAjaxFunction(endPoint1)
        .then(function (data) {
            return data.d.results.length > 0 ? data : myAjaxFunction(endPoint2)
        }).then(function(data) {
            return data.d.results.length > 0 ? data : myAjaxFunction(endPoint3)
        }).then(function(data) {
            // Whichever one was found will end up down here
            console.log("The data found was", data);
        }).catch(function(e) {
            console.error(e);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for share the inputs... but in this case .. it will execute all the thens.

Comment: @nbi So what if it executes all the thens? It will only call `myAjaxFunction()` until it finds a match and then not call it anymore.